# how to connect to open wifi?

Tags: wi-fi

I cant connect to open wifi with my Samsung A5. When I try to connect to wifi,  page immediately pop up and it writes that I cant connect (I do not get the public website to agree to the terms and connections like others). Do I need to change something in my options?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this page? It's tricky to be sure of what's happening without seeing it.